# Clustered HTTP server that syncs clients for file transfer

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a Node HTTP server that essentially only exists for NAT punchthrough. Its job is to facilitate a client sending a file, and another client receiving that file.

Edit: The clients are other Node processes, not browsers. We're using Websockets because some client locations won't allow non-HTTP/S port connections.

The overall process works like this:

1. All clients keep an open websocket connection.
2. The receiving client (`Alice`) tells the server via Websocket that it wants a file from another client (`Bob`).
3. The server generates a unique token for this transaction.
4. The server notifies `Alice` that it should download the file from `/downloads?token=xxxx`. `Alice` connects, and the connection is left open.
5. The server notifies `Bob` that it should upload the file to `/uploads?token=xxxx`. `Bob` connects and begins uploading the file, since `Alice` is already listening on the other side.
6. Once the transfer is complete, both connections are closed.

This is all accomplished by storing references to the HTTP `req` and `res` objects inside of a `transfers` object, indexed by the `token`. It all works great... as long as I'm not clustering the server.

In the past, when I've used clustering, I've converted the server to be stateless. However, that's not going to work here: I **need** the `req` and `res` objects to be stored in a state so that I can pipe the data.
I know that I could just buffer the transferring data to disk, but I would rather avoid that if at all possible: part of the requirements is that if I buffer anything to disk I must encrypt it, and I'd rather avoid putting the additional load of encrypting/decrypting transient data on the server.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how I could implement this in a way that supports clustering, or a pointer to further research sources I could look at?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but do you **need** to keep the files on the server?  Have you considered just skipping the middleman and having the clients connect directly over WebRTC or does this whole transaction need to be async (I'll upload it now, but Alice can download it hours later)?

Comment: @zero298, as long as we can make the same TLS guarantees with WebRTC connections that should be fine. I must confess, I am a bit behind and have never done anything with WebRTC. I'll have to look into it.